# Set parent attribute on child level

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

A customer of ours uses XSL FO for generating PDF output. He has an issue with descriptions in a table where the cells are split over the page end. The limitation is that he uses an XSL editor instead of direct XSL. This editor lets you add XSL snippets, but you cannot access all the levels of the XSL.

Switching to XSL without an editor is not an option.

In XSL a simple solution will look like:

```
<fo:table-row>
<xsl:attribute name="keep-together.within-page">always</xsl:attribute>
<fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

But the table-row tag is not accessible from the editor. I can set it on a table-cell level. Is that possible?

So something like:

```
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell>
<xsl:attribute name="../keep-together.within-page">always</xsl:attribute>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Comment: @LaurentiuL. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: @michael.hor257k Cool, thanks! That was illuminating

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's possible within your editor, but perhaps the following example may help:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <row>
        <cell>Alpha</cell>
        <cell>Bravo</cell>
        <cell>Charlie</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Delta</cell>
        <cell>Echo</cell>
    </row>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cell[1]">
    <xsl:attribute name="add">True</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<root>
   <row add="True">
      <cell>Alpha</cell>
      <cell>Bravo</cell>
      <cell>Charlie</cell>
   </row>
   <row add="True">
      <cell>Delta</cell>
      <cell>Echo</cell>
   </row>
</root>
```

This works because when the first `cell` is beginning to be processed, the parent `row` still has no children - so it is still possible to create an attribute and have it "adopted" by the parent `row`.

If you remove the `[1]` predicate, you will get an error along the lines of `"Cannot write an attribute node when no element start tag is open"` when processing any cell beyond the first one in row. Depending on your processor, this error may be fatal or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael. I tried it, but the editor does not seem to understand this solution. Also I have the issue that the value of "keep-together.within-page" needs to be set per row. Because if we set it for all rows, long descriptions will also be cropped on one page.

Comment: "*the value of "keep-together.within-page" needs to be set per row.*" Not sure what you mean by that. It probably doesn't matter anyhow, since it's not likely you'll be able to use a modified version either. I don't know of any other way (in XSLT) to add an attribute to an element that isn't the current node. If your tool doesn't let you to dictate how the row nodes should be transformed, then your question isn't about XSLT.